# App terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app i'm receiving this error: "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue", and the app crashes.
I'm showing a web page, but the problem is that the memory usage is not too hight, the app uses less than 100 MB of memory. The app crashes only if i run the app in a iPhone 6 Plus, in an iPhone 5 it works correctly.
How can i prevent the app to crash?
The app crashes only on rotation, so the webview is already loaded.

Comment: Use `WKWebView`. Its memory is allocated out of process (this means it won't be counted toward your app's memory used). Profile your app and see where you are using the most memory. Cache things, check for circular references/retained zombie objects.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: without wkwebview is not possible to remove this error.